# Pass data from activity to fragment on receiving a broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, fragment

There are lots of discussions about data exchange between activities and fragments, but I am still struggeling with a design flaw.

I have an activity that needs to receive some data from an service. When this data has changed, the service sends a local broadcast and the activity needs to get the latest dataset.

```
public class ActivityChannelConfig extends Activity implements FragmentChannelList.FragmentChanneListInferface, FragmentCustomChannelList.FragmentCustomChannelListInterface {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Bind to Bluetooth Service
    bindService(new Intent(this, ServiceBluetoothConnection.class), 
             mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                   IBinder service) {
        ActivityChannelConfig activity = mActivity.get();
        if(activity == null)
            return;

        ServiceBluetoothConnection.BTConnServiceBinder binder = (ServiceBluetoothConnection.BTConnServiceBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mIsBound = true;

        // Put current list into channel list fragment
        FragmentCustomChannelList customChannelList = (FragmentCustomChannelList)activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(activity.TAG_FRAGMENT_CUSTOMIZE);
        if(customChannelList != null) {
            customChannelList.setChannelList(activity.mServiceConnection.getService().getmDBMeasurement().getSortedMeasChannels(DBMeasurement.MEAS_CHANNEL_FLAG.MEAS_CHANNEL_ENABLED));
        }

        FragmentChannelList channelList = (FragmentChannelList)activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(activity.TAG_FRAGMENT_LIST);
        if(channelList != null) {
            channelList.setChannelList(activity.mServiceConnection.getService().getmDBMeasurement().getSortedMeasChannels(DBMeasurement.MEAS_CHANNEL_FLAG.MEAS_CHANNEL_ENABLED));
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final ActivityChannelConfig activity = mActivity.get();
    // Bail out if the ActivityMarwisApp is gone.
    if (activity == null)
        return;

    // Channel list has changed
        if(intent.getAction().equals(DBMeasurement.INTENT_DB_CHANNEL_LIST_CHANGED)) {
        // Put current list into channel list fragment

        FragmentCustomChannelList customChannelList = (FragmentCustomChannelList)activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(activity.TAG_FRAGMENT_CUSTOMIZE);
        if(customChannelList != null) {
                customChannelList.setChannelList(activity.mServiceConnection.getService().getmDBMeasurement().getSortedMeasChannels(DBMeasurement.MEAS_CHANNEL_FLAG.MEAS_CHANNEL_ENABLED));
        }

        FragmentChannelList channelList = (FragmentChannelList)activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(activity.TAG_FRAGMENT_LIST);
        if(channelList != null) {
                channelList.setChannelList(activity.mServiceConnection.getService().getmDBMeasurement().getSortedMeasChannels(DBMeasurement.MEAS_CHANNEL_FLAG.MEAS_CHANNEL_ENABLED));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now my problem is that I don't know, how to pass this data to the fragments inside my activity initial and dynamically. There always is the problem, that the fragment might ne be created when the service is connected or the broadcast is received.

Do I need to implement a two way interaction between the fragment and the activity?

activity.updateList -> fragment

fragment.getCurrentList -> activity

Or should I register a new braodcast receiver in each fragment, which might lead to lots of redundant code?

I know that I could also pass the data using the onCreate Bundle. But I am not a fan of making all that stuff parcable, which I also belive is very slow and inefficient.

Comment: are you try to communicate activity to fragment using interface?

Answer (score 0):

You can use local broadcast manager to communicate between multiple fragments and intents

```
//Send Broadcast
private void sendLocationBroadcast(Intent intent, Context context, String Message){
    intent.putExtra("Message", Message);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

 //In this snippet you point out your fragment or activity by given sample

 if(Origin == Enum_Fragments.Task.getInteger())
        {
            intent = new Intent("Task");
            sendLocationBroadcast(intent, context, "Task");
        }

 // What I have done here is made a enum for fragments and trigger service with related Identity (which was assigned by me to each fragment) after condition identifies the Argument (Origin) it will send data to desired framgment
```

Here is enum class for ref

```
public enum Enum_Fragments{

        Task(1), Frag Notes(2), Default(0);

Enum_Fragments(int s) {
    INTEGER_FOR_MODULE = s;
}

private int INTEGER_FOR_MODULE;

public int getInteger() {
    return INTEGER_FOR_MODULE;
}

public void setInteger(int iNTEGER_FOR_MODULE) {
    INTEGER_FOR_MODULE = iNTEGER_FOR_MODULE;
}

public static Enum_Fragments value(String i) {
    try {
        return valueOf(i);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return Default;
    }
}
```

this will send your broadcast for provided intent with some particular data after job done you may receive it at the activity as follows

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String Message = intent.getStringExtra("Message");

        //Todo

        Log.d("Local BroadCast", "Recieved " + Message);
    }
};
```

Comment: But I don't understand how this might solve my problem passing custom data to my fragments

Comment: You may send your custom data by using classes mention above through local broadcast manager you have to assign an integer code to all of your fragments / activities and through Service or any other activity send data seamlessly through origin code

Comment: BroadCastReceiver should only be used when system or application based actions needs to be notified. An instance can be used to pass data with the help of its public methods of the fragment. A fragnent manager will give an instance of  fragment if its needed.